# Animated rectangle used as an audio playhead isn't displaying properly

Tags: p5.js

I'm building a drum machine following a tutorial on Youtube, and I'm trying to use a rectangle as a playhead, which is animating in time with the beat.

The "Space" key activates the drum loop. The variable 'sPat' (sequence pattern), defined as an array [1, 2, 3... etc.] shows where the rectangle should be drawn. beatIndex represents the position taken from that array.

It seems to be working except the rectangle doesn't display most of the time, it's blinking and it is only visible about 5% of the time, randomly. I tried playing around with the rectangle parameters to see what is happenning, setting it to a fixed position and tried Firefox and Chrome. I'm not at all familiar with p5 yet.

What I need help with is:

1. why isn't the rectangle displaying?
2. why are the dots becomming colored in red as soon as I hit Space and how to prevent this?

I tried to minimize the code to a smaller working version. The 'sequence' function drawing the rectangle is at the end. You can also run it here: https://editor.p5js.org/dmihaescu/sketches/OFZm52gmF

```
let dum, dPat, dPhrase, drums;
let beatLength;
let sPat;
var canvas;
var cellWidth;
let beatIndex;

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(600, 100);
  beatLength = 16;
  cellWidth = width/beatLength;
  beatIndex = 0;
  
  dum = loadSound('assets/dum.flac', () => {});             
  dPat = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
  sPat = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
  
  drums = new p5.Part();
  drums.setBPM('45')
  
  drums.addPhrase('dum', (time) => {dum.play(time)}, dPat);
  drums.addPhrase('seq', sequence, sPat);
}

function keyPressed() { 
  if(key === " ") {
    if(dum.isLoaded()) {
      if(!drums.isPlaying) {
      drums.loop();
      } else {
        drums.stop();
      }
      } else {
        console.log("not yet loaded");
      }
    }
  }

function draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke("gray");
  strokeWeight(2);
  for (let i = 0; i < beatLength+1; i++) {
    line(i*width/beatLength, 0, i*width/beatLength, height);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    line(0, i*height/3, width, i*height/3);
  }

  noStroke();
  for (let i = 0; i < beatLength; i++) {
    if(dPat[i] === 1) {
    ellipse(i*width/beatLength+0.5*width/beatLength,height/2,10);
    }
  }
}

function sequence (time, beatIndex) {
  stroke('red');
  fill(255,0,0,50);
  rect((beatIndex-1)*cellWidth, 0, 50, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a seperate function just put the below code in draw function :-

```
  stroke('red');
  fill(255,0,0,50);
  rect((beatIndex-1)*cellWidth, 0, 50, height);
```

Try and tell whether it worked out or not